# How to create Jacobian at various linearization points of non linear system?

Tags: matlab

Create a Jacobian for linearization pts 1:N. I tried the above code but it give only one Jacobian rather than N.

```
N= input('nodes');
e5= ones(N,1);
e4= ones((N-1),1);
A = -2*diag(e5)+diag(e4,1)+diag(e4,-1);
v = sym('v');
n = symfun(sign(v)*v^2,v);
d = diff(n,v);
J = A;
v1 = (-N/2:N/2)';
 m = d(v1)
 for i=1:1:N
 for j=1:1:N
    if (i==j)
        J(i,j) = J(i,j)-m(i);
 end 
 end
```

Comment: you're going to have to be more explicit about what you're trying to calculate. what's the expression for the jacobian?

Comment: when linearizing any non linear system in control system there comes jacobian which i need to be calculated for the above system.

Comment: You can't use [`jacobian`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/jacobian.html) for this? Also, your code appears to be missing an `end`.

Comment: end is not an issue here.main issue is code..